# Hukkster technology stack

Tags: web-scraping

I started using Hukkster.com a few days ago. It is really fast and accurate. 
The bookmarklet of hukkster always fetches correct price from the product page. 
This happens for all the featured merchants it supports.

I was really curious to know what technology stack they might me using for such a fast and accurate response ?

I have tried to search everything I could on google. I found nothing other than Hukkster success story, Hukkster in NEWS etc. 
There was nothing related to technology stuff used by Hukkster.

Comment: why dont you contact Hukk team itself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is Mozenda .

Found it. Here it is:

http://blogs.wsj.com/venturecapital/2012/08/29/the-founders-creators-of-new-shopping-app-hukkster-definitely-not-brogrammers/

*The co-founders believed in their idea. There was just one problem–neither one knew how to code. They didn’t let that stop them. They developed a “paper prototype” that they could run without coding. **They built a crawler using a data extraction service called Mozenda**, and did the rest of Hukkster’s legwork with spreadsheets, emails and phones.*

http://www.mozenda.com/